# How to extract values from one list to loop list output?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

```py
import numpy as np
def trans_closeTo():
    
    header=['Town', 'Flat Type', 'Remaining Lease', 'Resale Price']
    price=int(input('Enter resale price amount:'))
    flat_type2=[[2,'2 room'],[3,'3 room'],[4,'4 room'],[5,'5 room'
    [6,'Executive'],[7,'Multi generation']]
    print()
    print(f'{header[0]:<15} {header[1]:<15}{header[-2]:<20}{header[-1]}')           

    data2= open('ASG1_data_dictionary.csv')
    data3= data2.readlines()
  
    dlist=[]
    
    for row in data:
        if price*0.95 <= row [8] <= price*1.05:
            whole_row=data3[int(row[0])].split(',')
            dlist.append([whole_row[0],row[1],row[7],row[8]])
     
    for town,flat,lease,resale in dlist:
            print(f'{town.capitalize():<15} {flat:<15}{int(lease):<20}. 
            {resale:.2f}')
 
trans_closeTo()
```

So I need the flat type output to be 'executive', '4room' and '5room' instead. I got the row[1] as my output. How can I use the list flat_type2 to link and have the strings for flat type as final output with the rest of the dlist?

Comment: This code contains syntactical errors.

Comment: `[5,'5 room'` is missing an ending bracket-comma `],`